# How to get max and min from set of values which contain double and integer in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

Here i need to get maximum and minimum values from set of numbers in which it contains double and integer and here i tried below code but it shows error and the error is `Cannot invoke 'max' with an argument list of type '([Any?])'` can anyone help me how to resolve this ?

Here is my code

```
   var facetsModel = [ListFacets]()

   for (key, value) in (dict as? [String:Any])! {
      print(key)
      print(value)
      var dict = [String:Any]()
      dict.updateValue(key , forKey: "price")
      dict.updateValue(value , forKey: "quantity")
      self.facetsModel.append(ListFacets.init(dict: dict))
    }
    let maxNum = max(self.facetsModel.map{$0.key})
    print(maxNum)
```

here is my model class

```
struct ListFacets {

    let key : Any?
    let value : Int?

    init(dict:[String:Any]) {
        if let price = dict["price"] as? Double {
            self.key = price
        }else {
           self.key =  dict["price"]
        }
        self.value = dict["quantity"] as? Int
    }

}
```

here dict data is shown here

> {
>       0 = 1;
>       "2.1" = 2;
>       21 = 3;
>       "31.5" = 2;
>       "9.45" = 1; }

Comment: So many questions. Why is your key `Any` when you want it to be a `Double`?  Why is the property called `key` when it is a price?  Why are you initialising from a dictionary?  Why are those properties optionals?

Comment: because it may be getting `Int` or `Double` value so i passed it as `Any` and i am just making it to pass to save in model class according to my convenience  @Paulw11

Comment: But the first thing you have said is that `key` is a string. You should convert that string to a double. There is no point in saving it as an int just because it happens to be a whole number instead of a float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't entirely clear what you are trying to do, but this is a much cleaner way of setting up your struct and finding the maximum price:

```
struct ListFacets {

    let quantity : Int
    let price : Double
}

var facetsModel = [ListFacets]()

let dict = ["0": 1, "2.1":2, "21":3, "31.5": 2, "9.45":1]

for (priceStr, quantity) in dict {
    if let price = Double(priceStr) {
        facetsModel.append(ListFacets(quantity: quantity, price: price))
    }
}


if let maxNum = facetsModel.max( by: { (a, b) -> Bool in
    return a.price < b.price
    }) {
        print(maxNum)
}
```

Comment: for getting min value same function as like max should be used @Paulw11

Comment: Yes, there is an equivalent min function that takes a closure as does max